# destructors of base and derived classes c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, destructor

I checked this code, and i saw that by the end of the function func() 
the destructor of base class have been called twice.
I dont understand why??
thank you..

```
class base  {
public:
    base(){cout << "ctor of base\n";}
    ~base(){cout << "d-ctor of base\n";}
};
class derived: public base 
{
public:
    derived(){cout << "ctor of derived\n";}
    ~derived(){cout << "d-ctor of derived\n";}
};
void func(base ob)
{
    cout << "inside func\n";
}
void main()
{
    derived ob; 
    func(ob);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c

Comment: @Csq Yes, it's sliced, but that doesn't explain *two* calls to `~base()`.

Comment: Don't forget the virtual destructor when polymorphism is at stake. here `~base()` should be `virtual ~base()`

Comment: @Angew I've written a more detailed answer.

Comment: Are you sure both destructions happen "by the end of the function `func()`," i.e. *before* the call to `system()`?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether `~base()` is virtual here or not, because you have an instance of `derived` (and not a `base` pointer which points to a derived) anyway. And a derived destructor will always call the base destructor.

Comment: @Angew
"by the end of the function func() the destructor of base class have been called twice" -- well, I cannot reproduce that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refactoring your base class like this:

```
class base  {
public:
    base(){cout << "ctor of base\n";}
    base(const base&) {cout << "copy-ctor of base\n";}
    ~base(){cout << "d-ctor of base\n";}
};
```

would issue the following output:

```
ctor of base
ctor of derived
copy-ctor of base
inside func
d-ctor of base
d-ctor of derived
d-ctor of base
```

Showing pretty clearly your base variable inside func was copied and then destroyed.

Comment: ok, i try it with another compiler and i saw that the base d-ctor ware called only once. that mean that its something wrong with my own compiler

Answer (score 2):

`base` is passed by value to `func`.
This means a sliced copy of `ob` will be created.

This will be destroyed as well as `ob` itself. The destructor of `ob` (`derived::~derived`) will automatically call the base classes destructor.

Therefore the `base` destructor is called two times.

Answer (score -1):

When you call the function you take the parameter by value. Therefore you create a local variable of type `base` in `func`.

When you return from `func`, the local variables are destroyed, so `ob`'s descrutor (which has type `base` is called.

You have to pass polymorphic types via reference or pointer.

This is called the slicing problem. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) link for details.

Comment: Still doesn't account for a second call to `~base()`; or where would that come from?

Comment: @Angew that is a good question, I [cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7750db094d86f26) that.